# Why is function not properly mapping to values while using purrr::possibly?

Tags: r, purrr

I'm trying to use `purrr::possibly()` to skip over errors in my code, but for some reason, when I use `possibly()` here, it returns the output as if everything is an error.

Here's an example:

```r
library(purrr)

add_things <- function(number) {
  
  new_number <- number + 1
  return(new_number)
  
}

possibly_add_things <- possibly(add_things, otherwise = NA)

# Works
map(c(1, 2, 3), possibly_add_things)
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 2
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] 3
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] 4

# Shouldn't be all NAs -- only the 2nd one
map(c(1, "hi", 3), possibly_add_things)
#> [[1]]
#> [1] NA
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] NA
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] NA
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that a `vector` is defined by its single type and the magnitude or length.  When, we use `c`, it is concatenating to a `vector` and based on the precedence of type, `character` is of higher precedence, thus all elements are converted to `character`. Instead, the input should be a `list`

```
map(list(1, 'hi', 3), possibly_add_things)
#[[1]]
#[1] 2

#[[2]]
#[1] NA

#[[3]]
#[1] 4
```

Comment: Ah, that is unbelievably silly on my part. Great insight, thanks!